# Finding the best direction for a bird escape from a radiation (function of 3 parametres)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I have this question. My bird is is in this point: (1,1,3) in 3D, and the source of the radiation is in that point too.

What is the direction for her to fly from that point, if it wants to minimize the radiation the quickest way?

The radiation expressed by:$$ R(x,y,z) = 1/((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-3)^2 + 1) $$

The gradient is (0,0,0) at this point, what is predictable, because in that point we have the max radiation (easy to see). 
If I understand correctly, this kind of exercizes we solve this way:
 1. Find the gradient
 2. If there arent any restrictions on the object, the maximal directions is the direction of the gradient (and the mminimal is minus the gradient)
 3. If there are restrictions, for example we are talking about a reptile, that cant fly any directions, but can only move above the surface, we need to find the N and do Gradint dot N = 0 and find the missing component (but in our case its not relevant).

So what do i do if the gradient is 0, as in this case ? Does it mean that any direction is good enough to minimize most quickly the radiation ? 
Or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, every direction is equivalent.

Comment: Does it correlates some how with the fact that the gradient is (0,0,0)? As i understand, it doesnt, but im trying to think, what would i do, if it wasnt simetric, because that is the nly reason i could think about logiclly.  
How can i find the direction in any another problem like this, if my gradient gets zero ? 
Or maybe it does has correlation ?

Comment: @user183297 The symmetry implies a gradient of $(0,0,0)$ in the point of symmetry, but not the other way. Imagine a bump with ellipses as equipotential lines. The center of the ellipse will still have a gradient of $(0,0,0)$, but clearly an ellipse isn't rotationally symmetric.

Comment: Exactly, so in the first place, when i see its simetric, ill know that every direction is equivalent. But what do i do if the gradient 0, but as you said it isnt simetric and i need to find the maximal or minimal direction ?
I mean, i must use for that the gradient, am I not ?
Because the direction is gradient / |gradient| (for the max for example).

Comment: And just to check myself, if there was a boy in the same place and a surface expressed by: $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y+z-5 = 0$, the answer is the minus gradient of this surface: (-2,-1,-1), right ? 
I dont use the radiation formula any case in this problem.